# Tagged interface not receiving packets?

Tags: networking, centos, ip, linux-networking, vlan

I have a VLAN ID `69` at interface `enp101s0f0` that's not receiving any packets:

```
enp101s0f0.69: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.15.2.5  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 10.15.2.7
    inet6 fe80::20f:53ff:fe56:2390  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0f:53:56:23:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
```

However the untagged interface is receiving packets tagged with VLAN ID `69`:

```
enp101s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::20f:53ff:fe56:2390  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0f:53:56:23:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5814204  bytes 485470187 (462.9 MiB)
```

as seen on `tcpdump`:

```
[root@box-04 ~]# tcpdump -i enp101s0f0 -nn -e vlan
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp101s0f0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:41:46.911547 2c:33:11:f9:9b:1e > 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cd, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 68: vlan 69, p 7, LLC, dsap SNAP (0xaa) Individual, ssap SNAP (0xaa) Command, ctrl 0x03: oui Cisco (0x00000c), pid PVST (0x010b), length 42: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 80af.2c:33:11:f9:9b:41.8097, length 42
```

I think the routing table is set up correctly:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.15.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.15.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
10.15.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 enp101s0f0.69
```

What can be the issue?

---

### EDIT

Here's `ip -s -s -d link show dev` for both interfaces:

```
[root@box-04 ~]# ip -s -s -d link show dev enp101s0f0
4: enp101s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq portid 000f53562390 state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:56:23:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    485969816  5820208  0       6       0       5815704
    RX errors: length   crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    4675014    72946    0       0       0       0
    TX errors: aborted  fifo   window heartbeat transns
               0        0       0       0       4
[root@box-04 ~]# ip -s -s -d link show dev enp101s0f0.69
6: enp101s0f0.69@enp101s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0f:53:56:23:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0
    vlan protocol 802.1Q id 698 <REORDER_HDR> addrgenmode eui64
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    0          0        0       0       0       0
    RX errors: length   crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    7832       36       0       0       0       0
    TX errors: aborted  fifo   window heartbeat transns
               0        0       0       0       2
```

Comment: This isn't a routing issue. Show, please, output of `ip -s -s -d link show dev enp101s0f0` and `ip -s -s -d link show dev enp101s0f0.69` commands.There are various reasons of this behaviour.

Comment: @AntonDanilov Thanks. I've posted the output.

Answer (score 1):

As can you see in the third line of the output of `ip -s -s -d link show dev enp101s0f0.69`, vlan id of this interface is **698**, not **69**. So, it's just a misconfiguration or a typo.

Comment: Fat finger typo when I was copying the text over. My apologies.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if it has helped. Also, better use the ip, not ifconfig. Ifconfig is a deprecated a long time ago (it even missing in new releases of distros) and it can provide an uncomplete view.

Comment: BTW just to clarify, I fixed the typo that was only when I pasted the text over here, there isn't a misconfiguration on my side, so the issue is still open. :(

Comment: Hm... So edit the question to provide the actual state of your environment.and I'll try to solve your issue. Can you capture more frames on the `enp101s0f0` interface? Are there other frame types, not only RSTP?